# Blank page WordPress custom theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom theme that worked over months, now for some reasons without any update it shows blank pages on all website even with WP_debug active and php display error it doesnt shows any error, now to debug the problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**If you can access the backend:**

1. Switch to any of the WP default themes and check if you still have the issue.
2. then deactivate all plugins and check for issues.
3. then activate plugin 1 by 1 and check for issues (activate the base plugin first then it's the add-on/dependent plugin)
4. if all these don't work, replace core files from FTP
5. at last contact a developer ask him to debug the issue

**If you can't access the backend:**

1. hire/contact a developer for debugging or ask hosting for help in this case.

Comment: The problem is the theme, i developed it, but this blank page without any error i dont know how to debug