# WordPress doesnt work, preview view show me nothing

Tags: wordpress

[image]

Unistall XAMPP
Unistall MySQL
ipconfig/flushdns, etc

Comment: Do you use any custom PHP or builder with the theme? Check the console see if there's any error codes in there

Comment: @Noobuyer This answer to another SO question might help you debugging your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73832481/8547214

Answer (score 1):

This may be a plugin or theme conflict. Please attempt to disable all plugins. If the problem goes away, enable them one by one to identify the source of your troubles.

If you can install plugins, install [“Health Check”](https://wordpress.org/plugins/health-check/). On the troubleshooting tab in Health Check, you can click the button to disable all plugins and change the theme for JUST you, while you’re still logged in, without affecting normal visitors to your site. You can then use its admin bar menu to turn on/off plugins and themes one at a time. See the [wordpress handbook for troubleshooting](https://make.wordpress.org/support/handbook/appendix/troubleshooting-using-the-health-check/) or this [article by Rank Math](https://rankmath.com/kb/check-plugin-conflicts/) for more information.

I hope this helped, if not let me know and we can look into it together.